# Passing a function (with arguments) as an argument in Python

Tags: python-3.x, benchmarking

I am measuring performance of different sorting methods using Python built-in library **timeit**. I would like to pass a function and an integer as arguments to the statement being tested in *timeit()*. I tried the following:

```
def sort_1(l):
    ...
    return l_sorted

def test(f: Callable, l_len: int):
    l = np.random.rand(low=-1000, high=1000, size=l_len)
    f(l)


timeit.timeit(stmt=test(sort_1, l_len=10), number=1000)
```

... with a ValueError saying that stmt is neither a string nor callable. The error doesn't occur when I call it like this:

```
timeit.timeit(stmt=test, number=1000)
```

... but then I cannot pass any argument to *test()*. What is a general solution if someone wants to pass arguments to a function given as an argument? (let's say, when a method is already implemented and there is not way to pass arguments in a separate argument)

Cheers

Edit:

@jonrsharpe, thanks! The solution looks like this:

```
timeit.timeit(stmt='test(f=sort_1, l_len=10)', number=100, globals=globals())
```

Comment: `lambda: test(...)`, or pass a string as shown in https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#examples?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I've included the suggested solution in the question. So a generic solution would be to use lambda?

Comment: @MightestDuck not `lambda` necessarily, but any way of partially applying the arguments. You could do `def time_me(): return test(f=sort_1, l_len=10)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I see what you mean. The problem of passing the arguments still remains when you want to loop through a list of different sorting functions and lengths. Thanks for your help! Since you answered in a comment I can't accept your answer, or can I?