# Python: passing some arguments to a function-argunment

Tags: python, function, networkx

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039221/passing-a-function-with-arguments-as-an-argument-in-python). Imagine I want to use the function `pairwise_distances` from `sklearn.metrics.pairwise`.

```
def network_analysis(G):
    pairwise_distances(G.nodes, G.nodes, metric=my_metric)
    # blah blah
    #
```

and I have

```
 def my_metric(x,y,G):
     return networkx.shortest_path(G,x,y)* (G.nodes[x]['weight']-G.nodes[y]['weight'])
```

However I don't know how to pass G to my metric in the `pairwise_distances` call.

As a side note this is a problem I've been having with Networkx because as nodes are identified by numbers, to each function which needs to work with node attributes I have to pass the whole network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't change `pairwise_distances`, try using [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial). This allows you to do the following:

```py
import functools

def network_analysis(G_input):
    new_metric = functools.partial(my_metric, G = G_input)
    pairwise_distances(G_input.nodes, G_input.nodes, metric = new_metric)
```

New-metric behaves like this:

```py
def new_metric(x, y):
    return my_metric(x, y, G)  # G has already been passed in via functools.partial
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I like it that Python has a tool for basically anything you want.